Fast matrix multiplication for large matrices in Python
I'm using Python to perform a Gram-Schmidt orthonormalisation procedure on the eigenvectors of a matrix using a Bogoliubov transformation. I don't know of any Python packages to implement this transformation, which means I have to run an explicit program checking the inner products of each pair of eigenvectors.
The problem is, I'm working with a matrix of size $80 \times 80$, so using the standard * operator to multiply Sympy matrices appears to take quite a bit of time, especially since this operation is being performed in a set of nested loops that selects a new eigenvector and orthogonalises it with respect to each previously orthonormalised eigenvector. Here is the code I'm using:
#orthonormalising remaining eigenvectors
norm_vect = [vect1]       #vect1 is the first eigenvector (orthonormalised prior to this)
for m in range(1, int(len(vect)/2)):  #vect is the output of the Sympy function Matrix.eigenvects() 
vect_m = np.array(vect[m][2][0])                  #m: current eigenvector

for n in range(len(norm_vect)):
    v_prev = norm_vect[n]                          #previously orthonormalised vectors

    #Matrix Multiplication
    vect_m = Matrix(vect_m)    #Sympy Matrix
    v_prev = Matrix(v_prev)

    sum_vect = complex((-Dagger(v_prev)*s3*vect_m)[0])   #Dagger function from Sympy
    #s3 is a diagonal matrix of size 80*80, with elements 1 or -1
    #v_prev and vect_m are column matrices of size 80*1

    if sum_vect != 0:
        a = 1/sum_vect
        vect_m = a*vect_m + v_prev

#normalising


sum_vect = float((Dagger(vect_m)*s3*vect_m)[0])


a = 1/np.sqrt(float(sum_vect))

vect_m = a*vect_m

norm_vect.append(vect_m)

In this code, the calculation of sum_vect in the nested loop is extremely slow, taking longer times for increasing n.
Is there any way I could increase the speed for this matrix multiplication, like alternative algorithms or Python functions or libraries?
I've also tried this by converting the Sympy matrices to Numpy arrays and using np.matmul and np.dot, but those seem to be taking longer times.
If there is a function or library to implement Bogoliubov transformations in Python, that would help too.
Thanks!

The problem is very likely because sympy computes eigenvalues and eigenvectors symbolically as algebraic numbers. Do you really need symbolic computation if you convert things to float in the end anyway? Try using the function numpy.linalg.eig to compute the eigenvectors.

I'll try that! Are there also any faster ways to do the matrix multiplication in the step I mentioned, without using Sympy? That appears to be the slowest step so far.

@AnanyaBiswas : Matrix-like array multiplication is provided in numpy by the .dot functions, the .matmulfunction and the @ operator. There is also more general support for Einstein summations.
